# Вывести время в формате "часы минуты"

Tags: php, mysql

Подскажите как вывести из колонки таблицы время в формате "часы:минуты".
Вывожу данные из таблицы кодом указанным ниже, но время выводится в формате часы:минуты:секунды. Понимаю что нужно форматировать как-то так: `echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');` Но не получилось. Помогите пожалуйста.

Вот так выводится информация из таблицы:

```
function show_list() 
{ 
  $query = 'SELECT show_id, show_time, show_title, show_author FROM schedule ORDER BY show_time ASC';
  $res = mysql_query($query); 
  echo '<h2>Список</h2>'; 
  echo '<table border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">'; 
  echo '<tr><th>ID</th><th>Время</th><th>Шоу</th><th>Автор</th><th>Редактировать</th><th>Удалить</th></tr>'; 
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) 
  { 
    echo '<tr>'; 
    echo '<td>'.$row['show_id'].'</td>'; 
    echo '<td>'.$row['show_time'].'</td>'; 
    echo '<td>'.$row['show_title'].'</td>'; 
    echo '<td>'.$row['show_author'].'</td>';
    echo '<td><a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?action=editform&id='.$row['show_id'].'">Редактировать</a></td>'; 
    echo '<td><a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?action=delete&id='.$row['show_id'].'">Удалить</a></td>'; 
    echo '</tr>'; 
  } 
  echo '</table>';
  echo '<p><a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?action=addform">Добавить</a></p>';  
}
```

Comment: Вы можете из базы выбрать сразу в нужном формате через [DATE_FORMAT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp) ...... типа `SELECT show_id, DATE_FORMAT(show_time, '%H:%i') as show_time, show_title, show_author FROM schedule ORDER BY show_time ASC`

Comment: date('H:i', $date) - если в БД дата хранится как timestamp

Comment: Пробовал. Не получается потом вывести в  echo. Делал запрос так: 'SELECT DATE_FORMAT (show_time, "H:i"), show_id, show_title, show_author FROM schedule ORDER BY show_time ASC';. Но как потом вывести, не понимаю. При echo '<td>'.$row['show_time'].'</td>';  ничего не выводит

Comment: В каком виде лежит в БД дата? Какой тип колонки?

Comment: @АртемНовиков а зачем `DATE_FORMAT` применять к `id` ?)) и наверное не выводится потому, что при применении функции колонка будет названа не так, как вы ожидали....т.е. колонка так и будет называться (`DATE_FORMAT(show_time, '%H:%i')`)... поэтому следует добавить алиас `as show_time`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я ошибся, там вместо   id я прописывал  time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$date = '2016-06-06 12:05:00';    
echo date('H:i',strtotime($date));
```

Вывод

```
12:05
```

Comment: Я должен прописать $date = 'SELECT show_time FROM schedule'? Чтоб получить дату из соответствующего столбца?

Comment: в переменную $date необходимо положить значение даты из БД

Comment: echo '<td>'.date('H:i',strtotime($row['show_time'])).'</td>';

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Получилось!